# PIMCORE: How to use localize field with object bricks

Tags: pimcore, pim

Can it possible to use localize field and objectbricks with combine? for eg.

1)

```
-- localized field
   -- objectbricks
```

2)

```
-- objectbricks
  -- localized field
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can use something like 'objectbrick' -> clasification store: https://www.pimcore.org/docs/latest/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Classification_Store.html

Clasification store can be translated into other languages